# Paste an image on another image of different size & display on matlibplot in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am new to python and I have wrote the following python code to paste  [spot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y8iW.jpg) onto  [background.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obxf4.jpg) at coordinate (2,3) given that background.jpg lies on extents [0,20, 0, 16]. Both images are of different sizes.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

# imbg is layout/ background
imbg = Image.open(r"background.jpg")
# imfg is furniture/ foreground
imfg = Image.open(r"spot.jpg")

# manually set aspect dimension for background
ext= [0,20,0,16]
ax = plt.subplot()  # add sub-plot

oi= OffsetImage(imfg, zoom= 0.1)
ab1= AnnotationBbox(oi, (2, 3), frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(ab1)

plt.imshow(imbg, zorder= 0, extent=ext )
plt.xlabel("Dimensions", fontsize= 12)
plt.title('Proposed', fontsize= 20)

mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.state("zoomed") 
plt.show()
```

Results is [matlibplot results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrqPt.jpg)

I see 3 problems here.

1. If I don't put zoom= 0.1 (a number I anyhow guess), spot.jpg will be very much bigger than background.jpg. In fact, spot is less than 1m by 1m and background is 20m by 16m. If I need to put a number to zoom in order to put both images to the same scale, what should be the number or how can I calculate the number?
2. When I zoom into the matplotlib results, spot.jpg doesn't seem to turn bigger. [zooming into spot on plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c0Si.jpg). I wonder why.
3. The image quality of spot is affected on the plot. Is there anyway to improve how spot.jpg look on plot?

Many thanks in advance to help a noob like me.

Answer (score 0):

Using an offset box maynot be the good approach here. It seems you want to have both images in the same data coordinates. Hence plot both images as `imshow` with different extents according to the desired positions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# imbg is layout/ background
imbg = plt.imread(r"data/room.jpg")
# imfg is furniture/ foreground
imfg = plt.imread(r"data/spot.jpg")

# manually set aspect dimension for background
ext= [0,20,0,16]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(imbg, zorder= 0, extent=ext )
ax.imshow(imfg, zorder= 1, extent=[2,5,3,6] )
ax.axis(ext)

plt.xlabel("Dimensions", fontsize= 12)
plt.title('Proposed', fontsize= 20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The extent for the chair is also rather arbitrary here, but you would know better where to put it and in what size.

Comment: Thanks ImportanceOfBeingErnest for your quick reply and it has helped me to overcome the problem.

Comment: by the way, I see 2 figures appearing- first is blank and the second one is what I want. How do I remove the first figure?

Comment: Sorry, there was one subplot too much in the code which was left over. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!